# Homological dimensions of rings of smooth functions

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

What is the global dimension of the algebra $C^\infty\mathbb R$ of smooth functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$? What is the global dimension of the algebra $(C^\infty\mathbb R)_0$ of germs of smooth functions at $0\in\mathbb R$?

Answers concerning other kinds of homological dimension or other manifolds are welcome; but this question is not about [topological homology theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4094), just pure algebra.

Comment: Do you have any aimed applications? It seems strange to me to deal with modules over the abstract ring of germs of smooth functions.

Comment: Not really. I just thought that these rings are so common and well-understood, so maybe people know the answer. I also thought it would be interesting to compare with the topological theory, cf. the link above.

Comment: The answer for the ring of holomorphic functions $\mathcal O(\mathbb C)$ is surprising, for me at least. Its global dimension is $\geq 3$, but it is impossible to compute it: for each $n\in\{3,4,5,...,\infty\}$, the statement "gl. dim. $\mathcal O(\mathbb C)=n$" is compatible with ZFC.
Christian U. Jensen, Propriétés homologiques et logiques des anneaux de fonctions entières. C. R. Acad. Se. Paris, t. 294 (22 mars 1982), série 1, p. 385 -- 386.
https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5533945n/f15.item
https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k55521439/f17.item

Answer (score 7):

Let $R$ be the ring of germs of smooth functions $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ at 0; I claim that $R$ has global dimension $d$.

In particular, for $M$ a $d$-dimensional manifold (without boundary), the ring of germs of smooth functions $f:M\to\mathbb R$ at $x\in M$ has global dimension $d$, and the ring of smooth functions on $M$ is of dimension at least $d$. I conjecture that it is precisely $d$ in the case of compact manifolds, but to be honest I do not have a clue how to prove it. I would not dare conjecture something for non-compact manifolds because not all maximal ideals are of the form $\{f:f(x)=0\}$ for some $x\in M$.

We will need the following fact from analysis: the ideal $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_k\rangle$ is precisely the ideal of functions vanishing at all points $(0,\ldots,0,x_{k+1},\ldots,x_d)$. This can be deduced from the fact that any smooth function $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ can be written
$$ f:x\mapsto f(0)+x_1g_1(x) + x_2g(x) + \ldots + x_dg(x) $$
with
$$ g_k:x\mapsto\int_0^1(\partial_kf)(0,\ldots,0,ux_k,x_{k+1}\ldots,x_d)\mathrm du. $$
In particular each $g_k$ is smooth and is identically zero whenever $f$ vanishes over $\{x_1=\cdots=x_{k-1}=0\}$.

*Proof of $\operatorname{gl dim}R=d$.* The ring $R$ is local, with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ the collection of functions vanishing at 0, hence its global dimension is the projective dimension of $R/\mathfrak m$ (Corollary 19.5 in [E]). By the above fact, $\mathfrak m=\langle x_1,\ldots,x_d\rangle$, and because of this characterisation again it is not hard to see that $x_1,\ldots,x_d$ is an $R$-[regular sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_sequence). In particular, the [Kozsul complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koszul_complex)
$$0\longrightarrow\Lambda^dR^d\longrightarrow\cdots\longrightarrow\Lambda^2R^d\longrightarrow\underbrace{\Lambda^1R^d}_{\simeq R^d}\longrightarrow\underbrace{\Lambda^0R^d}_{\simeq R}\longrightarrow R/\mathfrak m\longrightarrow0$$
sending $(g_1,\ldots,g_d)$ to $x_1g_1+\cdots+x_dg_d$ in degree 1 is a free resolution of $R/\mathfrak m$, so the quotient has projective dimension at most $d$. Moreover, upon tensoring the resolution by $R/\mathfrak m$ itself, all differentials are sent to zero, hence $\operatorname{Tor}^R_k(R/\mathfrak m,R/\mathfrak m)=(\Lambda^kR^d)\otimes(R/\mathfrak m)\simeq\Lambda^k(R/\mathfrak m)^d$, which is non-zero for $k=d$. This means $R/\mathfrak m$ has projective dimension at least $d$, i.e. precisely $d$, and indeed we find the global dimension of $R$ to be $d$.

[E] D. Eisenbud, *Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry* (1995).

Comment: By the way the Krull dimension is infinite for all rings these rings, but I assume that's not what you mean by “other homological dimensions”. Also both of these results can be proved in ZF, as far as I know.